# Kernel startup script only executes after notebook's first cell execution on jupyter lab

Tags: jupyter, jupyter-lab

I'm building a Jupyter Lab environment on for PySpark.

In this environment I have 3 kernel options:

- PySpark + Hive
- PySpark + Iceberg
- PySpark + Delta

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A2W2q.png)

I created 3 ipython profiles, one for each kernel. And for each Kernel I want to start a new document by selecting the kernel from the launcher menu and the first cell of the notebook already be populated with some code, for example:

```py
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession

spark = SparkSession \\
    .builder \\
    .appName("SparkSession-Iceberg") \\
    .config("spark.jars.packages", "org.apache.iceberg:iceberg-spark-runtime-3.2_2.12:1.3.0") \\
    .config("spark.sql.extensions", "org.apache.iceberg.spark.extensions.IcebergSparkSessionExtensions") \\
    .config("spark.sql.catalog.iceberg", "org.apache.iceberg.spark.SparkCatalog") \\
    .config("spark.sql.catalog.iceberg.type", "hive") \\
    .config("spark.sql.catalog.iceberg.uri", "thrift://hive-metastore:9083") \\
    .getOrCreate()

spark
```

(for the PySpark + Iceberg Kernel)

This way every time I want to start a new pyspark notebook I can have the spark sesison already typed in and ready to run.

I tried creating a startup script for the kernels. My script uses IPython to add a cell with the code I need:

```py
from IPython import get_ipython

hive_script = """# Spark Session - Hive

from pyspark.sql import SparkSession

spark = SparkSession\\
    .builder\\
    .appName("SparkSession-Hive")\\
    .getOrCreate()

spark"""

delta_script = """# Spark Session - Delta

from pyspark.sql import SparkSession

spark = SparkSession \\
    .builder \\
    .appName("SparkSession-Delta") \\
    .config("spark.jars.packages", "io.delta:delta-core_2.12:2.4.0") \\
    .config("spark.sql.extensions", "io.delta.sql.DeltaSparkSessionExtension") \\
    .config("spark.sql.catalog.spark_catalog", "org.apache.spark.sql.delta.catalog.DeltaCatalog") \\
    .enableHiveSupport() \\
    .getOrCreate()

spark"""

iceberg_script = """# Spark Session - Iceberg

from pyspark.sql import SparkSession

spark = SparkSession \\
    .builder \\
    .appName("SparkSession-Iceberg") \\
    .config("spark.jars.packages", "org.apache.iceberg:iceberg-spark-runtime-3.2_2.12:1.3.0") \\
    .config("spark.sql.extensions", "org.apache.iceberg.spark.extensions.IcebergSparkSessionExtensions") \\
    .config("spark.sql.catalog.iceberg", "org.apache.iceberg.spark.SparkCatalog") \\
    .config("spark.sql.catalog.iceberg.type", "hive") \\
    .config("spark.sql.catalog.iceberg.uri", "thrift://hive-metastore:9083") \\
    .getOrCreate()

spark""" 

shell = get_ipython()
if shell.kernel.config['IPKernelApp']['profile'] == 'pyspark_hive':
    script = hive_script
if shell.kernel.config['IPKernelApp']['profile'] == 'pyspark_delta':
    script = delta_script
if shell.kernel.config['IPKernelApp']['profile'] == 'pyspark_iceberg':
    script = iceberg_script

shell.set_next_input(f"{script}", replace=False)
```

but every time I start the kernel, I have to execute a first line of code before it really starts. See the gif below:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RTeUm.gif)

Is there any other alternative to do what I want in Jupyter Lab environment?

Comment: https://pypi.org/project/jupyterlab-templates/ ? I guess it could be enhanced to allow parametrizing kernel too.

Comment: Tried using jupyterlab-templates it but I didn't like the way it looked, I wanted those separate kernels in the launcher screen. I managed to come up with a different solution: I built a magic command on kernel startup, this way users cant start the kernel, execute %SparkSesison and get the right SparkSession creation cell in their notebook.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I managed to come up with a solution I'm satisfied with. I changed the kernel startup script to create a magic command instead of adding the cells by itself.

```py
from IPython.core.magic import register_line_magic
from IPython import get_ipython
from IPython.display import display, Markdown

@register_line_magic
def SparkSession(line):
    
    hive_script = """from pyspark.sql import SparkSession

spark = SparkSession\\
    .builder\\
    .appName("SparkSession-Hive")\\
    .getOrCreate()

spark"""

    delta_script = """from pyspark.sql import SparkSession

spark = SparkSession \\
    .builder \\
    .appName("SparkSession-Delta") \\
    .config("spark.jars.packages", "io.delta:delta-core_2.12:2.4.0") \\
    .config("spark.sql.extensions", "io.delta.sql.DeltaSparkSessionExtension") \\
    .config("spark.sql.catalog.spark_catalog", "org.apache.spark.sql.delta.catalog.DeltaCatalog") \\
    .enableHiveSupport() \\
    .getOrCreate()

spark"""

    iceberg_script = """from pyspark.sql import SparkSession

spark = SparkSession \\
    .builder \\
    .appName("SparkSession-Iceberg") \\
    .config("spark.jars.packages", "org.apache.iceberg:iceberg-spark-runtime-3.2_2.12:1.3.0") \\
    .config("spark.sql.extensions", "org.apache.iceberg.spark.extensions.IcebergSparkSessionExtensions") \\
    .config("spark.sql.catalog.iceberg", "org.apache.iceberg.spark.SparkCatalog") \\
    .config("spark.sql.catalog.iceberg.type", "hive") \\
    .config("spark.sql.catalog.iceberg.uri", "thrift://hive-metastore:9083") \\
    .getOrCreate()

spark""" 
    
    shell = get_ipython()
    profile = shell.kernel.config['IPKernelApp']['profile']
    profile_name = str(profile).replace('pyspark_', '').capitalize()
    
    if profile == 'pyspark_delta':
        script = delta_script
    elif profile == 'pyspark_iceberg':
        script = iceberg_script
    else:
        script = hive_script
        profile_name = 'Hive'
    
    
        
    session_details = f"""# SparkSession - {profile_name}
| Spark Session        | http://localhost:4040        |
|----------------------|------------------------------|
| Spark Master         | http://localhost:5050        |
| Spark Worker A       | http://localhost:5051        |
| Spark Worker B       | http://localhost:5052        | 
| Hive Metastore       | thrift://hive-metastore:9083 |

| MinIO Object Storage | http://localhost:9090 |
|----------------------|-----------------------|
| user                 | `admin`               |
| password             | `password`            |

- Use `%trino` or `%%trino` to run queries using Trino
- Use `%sparksql` or `%%sparksql` to run queries using SparkSQL
"""

    shell.set_next_input(f"{script}", replace=False)
    
    return display(Markdown(session_details))
```

now the users can start the kernel, use %SparkSession and get the cell according to the kernel they chose:

[image]